# Invalid schema definition: Could not parse schema when creating PubSub subscription

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to create a subscription with a delivery type "Write to BigQuery" and ***Use Topic schema*** and ***Write metadata*** options.
So i created Topic with following protobuf schema :
[image]

and a BigQuery table with additional columns for metadata specified in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#write-metadata).

[image]

When i try to create subscription with both Use Write Metadata and Use Topic schema options enabled,  i get the following error:

```
API returned error: "Invalid schema definition: Could not parse schema."
```

Using just Write Metadata or just Use Topic schema works fine and i am able to create subscription and receive msgs

Comment: What is the type of the date field in your BigQuery schema?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn its a Record with 2 nested integer fields seconds and nanos

Comment: Can you please update the question with your BigQuery table schema?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn just did. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an internal issue with how some nested records are processed. Please follow https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/267444753 for the investigation and fix.